# Visual Studio 2015 shortcut for check in

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

What is visual studio 2015 shortcut for check in? I want to select the solution, and click on a shortcut to check it in to source control.

Answer (score 0):

Is it like a team function you are looking for? Ctrl+0

You might find it here: http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/

Comment: It didn't work. I am using VS 2015 with VisualStudio Online team services. I am not using git